# Databound DataGridView not sorting date correctly

Tags: .net, vb.net, sorting, datagridview

My DataGridView is not sorting my date column correclty and it doesn't seem to be sorting it by String either. The column is bound to a date property, all is done using the designer.

The set which I'm viewing it on is 424 entries long, there should be two entries for each date and they should be next to each other (regardless if sorting by date or string)

The last few dozen entries are sorted correctly but the initial entries are not.

Initially every second entry at the start is correct. Here is an extract if some of the sorting it does.

(The beginning of the sorted grid is on the left, and the end of grid is on the right)

[image]

I've no idea what is causing this, or how to fix it. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Since you're not ONLY using the date in that grid, why don't you show us some of the other data? Can you just post a picture?

Comment: Additionally, it would behoove you to accept more of your answers, or you're going to soon find that people will be less willing to post answers to your questions.

Comment: @drachenstern: I will try and provide you the information you require as soon as possible, and in regards to my other unanswered questions, I am working on multiple problems some of which I haven't been able to reply to but will respond to all my questions where possible, but thanks

Comment: With the exception of one question, all your others are more than a week old. If you are asking new questions, you have had time to reply to three month old questions you asked. If someone provided an answer that helped you, accept it to acknowledge that.

Comment: What if nobody provides an acceptable answer, like on this question? I'm having this same issue too.

Answer (score 1):

Use the SQL you called to get the data to also ORDER BY date DESC or ASC. This will give you the SQL servers adaptation of the date order.

An example would be:

```
SELECT Name, Salary
FROM Employee
ORDER BY Start_Date DESC
```

This way you are not relying on the grid to accurately sort dates. Also check that there are no date locale settings in your grid control. It could be the locale is set to another country.

Comment: Also to note, your dates aren't all in 00/00/0000 format. Some are 0/00/0000. You may want to check this isn't the issue as well.

Comment: the data is not retrieved by sql, the data in the grid are properties of business objects